# API to retrieve data from an XML file into java objects

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I need a quick and a best way to retrieve data from an XML File  into vectors or java objets.

thanks.

Comment: But at first you need to get familiar with the SO FAQ section: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). You can see how it works [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html).

Comment: Also take a look at JAXB (MOXy, Metro, JaxMe, etc):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html